# Convert ascii to hex in javascript

Tags: javascript, hex

I would like to convert a string into a hex with javascript just the symbols.

So if i have a string:

http://www.mydomain.com

the conversion result would be:

http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Emydomain%2Ecom

notice the % instead of the 0x

Comment: So you only want to convert *some* ASCII characters to hex? Which of the symbols? (An entire list)

Comment: Can't you just loop and replace non ASCII characters with hex code? Probably easier with regex also...

Comment: What's wrong with `encodeURIComponent()`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That won't encode, for example, `!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
var url = 'http://example.com';
var escaped = url.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, function(match) {
    var hex = match.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    return '%' + (hex.length < 2 ? '0' + hex : hex);
});
console.log(escaped); // => "http%3a%2f%2fexample%2ecom"
```

`[^A-Za-z0-9]` means "anything that's NOT a letter or number" (`^` means not when placed at the beginning of a character class).

When passing a function to `replace`, it will call that function (with the match as an argument) instead of replacing with a static string.

`charCodeAt` will get the character code of a specified character (by the argument), so `charCodeAt(0)` gets the character code of the first character.

`toString` takes an option base argument specifying which base you want, and base 16 is hex.

And finally, `(hex.length < 2 ? '0' + hex : hex)` will add a leading zero in case the resulting hex is only one digit.